# How to show nested object with different Store from ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, single-page-application, sencha-architect

I want to have REST operations on child object of a parent object on Ext Grid. I need to use rowExpander not rowWidget since I am using modern toolkit.

Here is my sample JSON data from my API:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 20,
    "total": 1,
    "hasPreviousPage": false,
    "hasNextPage": false
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "customer": "Mark",
      "dateRented": "2021-02-09T21:18:40.667",
      "movieRentals": [
        {
          "id": 5,
          "rentalDetailDtoId": 2,
          "movie": "Shingeki no Kyojin",
          "dateReturned": null
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "rentalDetailDtoId": 2,
          "movie": "Insidous 2",
          "dateReturned": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "customer": "Samuel",
      "dateRented": "2021-02-09T21:17:18.403",
      "movieRentals": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "rentalDetailDtoId": 1,
          "movie": "Home Alone",
          "dateReturned": null
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "rentalDetailDtoId": 1,
          "movie": "Neighbors",
          "dateReturned": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to display it per Customer and I have a REST action of POST on the movieRentals object. I would like to use RowExpander but I am not sure how to make it work.

Here is my current ExtJS Grid code:

```
Ext.define('Vidly.view.rental.DisplayRentalsView', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    xtype: 'displayrentalsview',
    reference: 'rentallist',
    title: 'Rental List',
    controller: 'displayrentalsviewcontroller',
    viewModel: 'rentalsviewmodel',
    reference:'displayrentalsviewgrid',
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    selModel:
    {
        mode: 'SINGLE'
    },
    viewConfig:
    {
        stripeRows: true
    },
    listeners: {
        selectionchange: 'onSelectionChange',
        show: 'onShow',
    },
    bind: {
        store: '{RentalListStore}'
    },
    itemConfig: {
        viewModel: true 
    },
    plugins: {
        pagingtoolbar: true
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            docked: 'top',
            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'left',
                    xtype: 'button',
                    ui: 'decline',
                    itemId: 'returnRental',
                    text: 'Return Rental',
                    reference: 'btnReturnRental',
                    handler: 'onReturnClick',
                    disabled: true,
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    columns: [
        {
            text: "Customer",
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'customer',
            editor:
            {
                allowBlank: false
            },
        },
        {
            text: "Movie",
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'movieRental',
            editor:
            {
                allowBlank: false
            },
        },
        {
            text: "Date Rented",
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'dateRented',
            editor:
            {
                allowBlank: false
            },
            renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
                if (value != null && value != "") {
                    var dateRented = new Date(Date.parse(value))
                    return Ext.Date.format(dateRented, 'm/d/Y')
                }
                else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Date Returned",
            flex: 1,
            dataIndex: 'dateReturned',
            editor:
            {
                allowBlank: false
            },
            renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
                if (value != null && value != "") {
                    var dateRented = new Date(Date.parse(value))
                    return Ext.Date.format(dateRented, 'm/d/Y')
                }
                else {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to provide an fiddle when your asking something in ExtJs

I Provided a fiddle here, I hope this helps you along

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3bpk

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        const store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            data: [{
                "id": 2,
                "customer": "Mark",
                "dateRented": "2021-02-09T21:18:40.667",
                "movieRentals": [{
                    "id": 5,
                    "rentalDetailDtoId": 2,
                    "movie": "Shingeki no Kyojin",
                    "dateReturned": null
                }, {
                    "id": 6,
                    "rentalDetailDtoId": 2,
                    "movie": "Insidous 2",
                    "dateReturned": null
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 1,
                "customer": "Samuel",
                "dateRented": "2021-02-09T21:17:18.403",
                "movieRentals": [{
                    "id": 3,
                    "rentalDetailDtoId": 1,
                    "movie": "Home Alone",
                    "dateReturned": null
                }, {
                    "id": 4,
                    "rentalDetailDtoId": 1,
                    "movie": "Neighbors",
                    "dateReturned": null
                }]
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Grid', {
            store: store,
            plugins: {
                rowexpander: true
            },
            height: 500,
            width: '100%',
            itemConfig: {
                body: {
                    tpl: '<ul>' +
                        '<tpl foreach="movieRentals">' +
                        '<li>Movie: {movie}</li>' +
                        '</tpl>' +
                        '</ul>'
                }
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'customer',
                width: 200
            }, {
                text: 'dateRented',
                dataIndex: 'dateRented',
                width: 250
            }],

            layout: 'fit',
            fullscreen: true
        });
    }
});
```

and  by the way, move those renderers into your viewController. Duplicate code is always ugly :-)

Comment: Great thanks for this but I am hoping to make a Rest Action with every movieRental. The parent object and child object has different stores.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should take a deeper look at the https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.Row.html#events

```
itemConfig: {
  body: {
    tpl: '<p>Hello World</p>',
    listeners: {
      beforeshow: sender => {
        console.log(sender);
        // Here you can tell your record to fetch data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

feel free to play arround with the fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3bq5&view/editor